# Where 'SYSKEY' password store? and what kind of algorithm it use to encrypt the passord?

Tags: windows-7, security, passwords

As far as I know Windows store user-acconts passwords in `SAM` file under `Windows\System32` and it use **NTLM** algorithm to encrypt it!

As you know we can set another password for windows (not for accounts) using `syskey` in **Run** windows.

I want to know :

Q1: Where this password store?

Q2: What kind of algorithms Windows use to encrypt it?

Q3: How can I disable this password after enabling it?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Where this password stored?**

From [System Key Utility Technical Overview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994564%28v=ws.10%29.aspx):

> **The SysKey utility lets you choose where that startup key is stored**. By default, the computer generates a random key and scatters it throughout the registry; a complex obfuscation algorithm ensures that the scatter pattern is different on every Windows installation.

You can change this to one of two other Syskey modes: you can continue to use a computer-generated key but store it on a floppy disk, or you can have the system prompt during startup for a password that is used to derive the master key.

**What kind of algorithms Windows use to encrypt it?**

From [Windows Password Recovery - windows passwords FAQ](http://www.passcape.com/windows_password_recovery_windows_faq):

> For hashing user passwords, Windows NT uses two algorithms: LM, which we have inherited from Lan Manager networks, which is based on a simple DES encryption, and NT, based upon the MD4 hashing function.

LM, as the weaker and vulnerable one, is not supported by default by the latest Windows Vista and Windows 7; however, you can still enable it. It is important to know that when the LM hashing option is on (it is enabled by default in Windows XP), all user passwords are considered quite vulnerable. Cracking the majority of such passwords normally takes just a few minutes.

The NT hash is free from the disadvantages, common to the LM hash. Consequently, it is much harder to pick the right password to a known NT hash than to an LM hash. But the current trend of increasing the computing power of modern computers, especially when using GPU, possibly, will make this standard too vulnerable to potential attackers.

From [Passwords Technical Overview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994558%28v=ws.10%29.aspx):

The LM hash is computed as follows:

- The password is padded with NULL bytes to exactly 14 characters. If the password is longer than 14 characters, it is replaced with 14 NULL bytes for the remaining operations.
- The password is converted to all uppercase.
- The password is split into two 7-byte (56-bit) keys.
- Each key is used to encrypt a fixed string.
- The two results from step 4 are concatenated and stored as the LM hash.

The LM OWF algorithm is included in Windows for backward compatibility with software and hardware that cannot use newer algorithms.

The NT hash is simply a hash. The password is hashed by using the **MD4 algorithm** and stored.

**How can I disable this password after enabling it?**

From [Windows 7: SysKey - Set Startup Password to Lock or Unlock Windows](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/243880-syskey-set-startup-password-lock-unlock-windows.html). Instructions and screenshoots are included.

Summary:

- Press the Windows+R keys to open the Run dialog, type syskey, and click OK.
- If prompted by UAC, then click Yes (Windows 7/8) or Continue (Vista).
- Click Update.
- Select System Generated Password, select Store Startup Key Locally, click OK.
- Enter the startup password and click OK.
- Click OK.
- Windows will now no longer require users to enter the startup password at every system startup.

Comment: @TheGoodUser-Sp The second part of the answer is not correct. The system key utility provides an extra obfuscation layer which is not officially documented by Microsoft. Additional information: [SysKey and the SAM](http://moyix.blogspot.it/2008/02/syskey-and-sam.html), [Windows 2k/NT/XP's syskey encryption](http://s-t-d.org/mirrors/syskey/syskey.txt).